# How can I differentiate recursively two folders and then copy the difference in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 folders that I need to merge so that when there are differences in sub-folders these differences will be copied to sub_folder with the same name in the second folder for eg.  we have "folder1" and "folder2" and they both have subfolder "sub_folder" but "sub_folder" in "folder1" have files "a.txt", "b.txt" and "c.txt" and "sub_folder" in "folder2" contains files: "c.txt", "d.txt" and "e.txt, my goal here is to merge them so that "sub_folder" in "folder2" have "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "d.txt", "e.txt". How can I achieve this effect

Code I included just puts the difference in the "temp" folder and that's enough, the problem is that when I have a subfolder with the same name in both folders my function will just pass by such folder even though these subfolders have different files inside.

```
function relocating_site(){  
    $folder = 'folder1';
    $folder2 = 'folder2';
    $file_list_1=array_diff(scandir($folder),scandir($folder2));
        $file_list=array_diff($file_list, array('..', '.')); 
        foreach($file_list as $file){
            if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME)===$file){
               exec('robocopy '.$folder."\\".$file." temp\\".$file." /E");
               echo $file."<br>";
            }
            else{
               $new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
               exec('copy '.$folder.'\\'.$file." temp\\".$file);
               echo $file."<br>";
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: You can simply use `glob()` and then `array_diff()`

Comment: Is glob() searching recursively by itself?

Comment: Research/search PHP 5 RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this to get the full pathnames of all the files - first in folder 1 then in folder 2. Once you have the 2 arrays you can simply perform `array_diff()`

```
// PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE   - go into subdirectorys looking for more files
// PREG_FIND_DIRMATCH    - return directorys that match the pattern also
// PREG_FIND_DIRONLY     - return only directorys that match the pattern (no files)
// PREG_FIND_FULLPATH    - search for the pattern in the full path (dir+file)
// PREG_FIND_NEGATE      - return files that don't match the pattern
// PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC - Instead of just returning a plain array of matches,
//                         return an associative array with file stats
// to use more than one simply seperate them with a | character
function preg_find($pattern, $start_dir='.', $args=NULL)
{
  $files_matched = array();
  $fh = @opendir($start_dir);
  if($fh)
  {
    while (($file = readdir($fh)) !== false)
      {
        if (strcmp($file, '.')==0 || strcmp($file, '..')==0) continue;
        $filepath = $start_dir . '/' . $file;
        if (preg_match($pattern, ($args & PREG_FIND_FULLPATH) ? $filepath : $file))
        {
          $doadd =     is_file($filepath)
                   || (is_dir($filepath) && ($args & PREG_FIND_DIRMATCH))
                   || (is_dir($filepath) && ($args & PREG_FIND_DIRONLY));
          if ($args & PREG_FIND_DIRONLY && $doadd && !is_dir($filepath)) $doadd = false;
          if ($args & PREG_FIND_NEGATE) $doadd = !$doadd;
          if ($doadd)
          {
            if ($args & PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC) // return more than just the filenames
            {
              $fileres = array();
              if (function_exists('stat'))
              {
                $fileres['stat'] = stat($filepath);
                $fileres['du'] = $fileres['stat']['blocks'] * 512;
              }
              //if (function_exists('fileowner')) $fileres['uid'] = fileowner($filepath);
              //if (function_exists('filegroup')) $fileres['gid'] = filegroup($filepath);
              //if (function_exists('filetype')) $fileres['filetype'] = filetype($filepath);
              //if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) $fileres['mimetype'] = mime_content_type($filepath);
              if (function_exists('dirname')) $fileres['dirname'] = dirname($filepath);
              if (function_exists('basename')) $fileres['basename'] = basename($filepath);
              //if (isset($fileres['uid']) && function_exists('posix_getpwuid ')) $fileres['owner'] = posix_getpwuid ($fileres['uid']);
              $files_matched[$filepath] = $fileres;
          }
            else array_push($files_matched, $filepath);
          }
        }
        if ( is_dir($filepath) && ($args & PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE) ) $files_matched = array_merge($files_matched, preg_find($pattern, $filepath, $args));
      }
    closedir($fh);
    }
  return $files_matched;
}
```